# Can I write multiple times to a file asynchronously in deno?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, deno

The **nodejs** documentation says the following about this issue:

> It is unsafe to use fs.write() multiple times on the same file without waiting for the callback. For this scenario, fs.createWriteStream() is recommended.

Now, I couldn't find anything about it in the deno documentation and I would like to know if deno also advises against making multiple *writes* on the same file in short frequency or if they have handled it differently through Rust.
If they do advice against it, what is the recommended way to solve this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Async `write` without waiting for promise completion is unsafe also for deno.

For a practical demo:

```
// If safe the file content would be ABCDEFGHIJ
async function main() {
  let n = new Uint8Array(1);
  const file = await Deno.open("bar.txt", { write: true, create: true });
  for (var i = 65; i < 75; i++) {
    n[0] = i;

    Deno.write(file.rid, n);
  }
}

main();
```

on my linux box `bar.txt` content is not `ABCDEFGHIJ` but `JJ'.

Note that this particular example actually shows two issues:

- no safe access to file resource using `Deno.write` without `await`
- sharing of the same last `i` loop variable value `J` between `write()` calls.